# Looks like there is a bug in MySQL UpdateXML

Tags: mysql, xml

I tried this query in Workbench and wonder why the second update `//b[2]` did not change?

```
SET @xml = '<a><b>111</b><b>222</b><b>333</b></a>';

SELECT
    UpdateXML(@xml, '/a/b[1]',  
    Concat('<e>', Extractvalue(@xml,'//b[1]'),'</e>')) INTO @xml;

SELECT
    UpdateXML(@xml, '/a/b[2]',  
    Concat('<e>', Extractvalue(@xml,'//b[2]'),'</e>')) INTO @xml;

SELECT
    UpdateXML(@xml, '/a/b[3]',  
    Concat('<e>', Extractvalue(@xml,'//b[3]'),'</e>')) INTO @xml;

SELECT @xml
```

Here's the result:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| @xml                                   |
+----------------------------------------+
|'<a><e>111</e><b>222</b><e>333</e></a>' |
+----------------------------------------+
```

The middle `<b>222</b>` should supposed to be changed to `<e>222</e>`. I've already checked every single letter in my code repeatedly.

Help please!...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your updates are always effectively replacing some `<b>` tag with an `<e>` tag at a certain index. Changes to `@xml` are cumulative. I.e., each statement is receiving the value of `@xml` updated by the previous statement.

Since you are mutating `@xml`, the first statement replaces the first `<b>` tag with an `<e>` tag. After running the first statement, `@xml` will look like this:

```
<a><e>111</e><b>222</b><b>333</b></a>
```

The second statement will start with the above value and then seek and mutate the second `<b>` tag still present (i.e., the last one):

```
<a><e>111</e><b>222</b><e>333</e></a>
```

Finally the last statement will start with the value above and try to seek the third `<b>` tag. Since there is only one `<b>` tag left (the middle tag), the last statement does nothing.

Here's a working version:

```sql
SET @xml = '<a><b>111</b><b>222</b><b>333</b></a>';

SELECT
    UpdateXML(@xml, '/a/b[1]',  
    Concat('<e>', Extractvalue(@xml,'//b[1]'),'</e>')) INTO @xml;

SELECT
    UpdateXML(@xml, '/a/b[1]',  
    Concat('<e>', Extractvalue(@xml,'//b[1]'),'</e>')) INTO @xml;

SELECT
    UpdateXML(@xml, '/a/b[1]',  
    Concat('<e>', Extractvalue(@xml,'//b[1]'),'</e>')) INTO @xml;

SELECT @xml
```

In the version above, the code is always replacing the first `<b>` tag in `@xml`. Here's how the value of `@xml` is updated:

- After the 1st statement: `<a><e>111</e><b>222</b><b>333</b></a>`
- After the 2nd statement: `<a><e>111</e><e>222</e><b>333</b></a>`
- After the 3rd statement: `<a><e>111</e><e>222</e><e>333</e></a>`.

Comment: Hahaha!!.. I got confused with iteration! the `b` is moving by the in each iteration. Now, I know. Solved! Thank you!

However, in your last statement, it seems there is something wrong with my approach. Why after the 2nd statement resulted to `111222333`. I got confused again.

Do you suggest there is a better way to do it? or could I avoid the iteration instead and do it in one statement?

Comment: By the way, I will be doing this iteration in prepared statement.

Comment: Very good. It seems to me that this update should only require one statement, not three, but I'm no `UPDATEXML` expert.

Comment: @RickyBelmont, sorry, I didn't understand your first question, can you please clarify what exactly is unexpected? The `UpdateXML` function does nothing when `xpath_expr` matches multiple nodes (see [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html#function_updatexml) for further info).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Please ignore my first question. I got it already. Many many thanks.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for swinging by here. With your comment, I know where you're coming from. Care for some light here? I did explored already `Load_File`, `Load_Data`, and this one I like `Load XML`. I've been also with Delphi and C# but the concerns are speed and bulk of data. Right now, I am working on MySQL workarounds. Enlighten me please?